# Calculate coordinate of center of a circle

Tags: trigonometry

I am working on a system to detect where a noise is located based on three microphones.
The microphones are A, B and C. The location of the sound is D.

If A has coordinates [0,0], B has coordinates [500,0], C has the coordinates [1000,0], and with the rule that the Y coordinate of D must be > 0, how can the coordinate of D be calulated with only the measurements given in the image? (Circle D must be tangent to the two circles, and pass through B)

[image]

My attempts to far:

- I tried to draw it geometrically, and tried to calculate along each step. This failed when I did not know the angle of the line AD relative to the base line.
- I tried to set up equations in the hope to make some substitutions but did not bring me to any result either:

BD = AD - 520

BD = CD - 300

Nothing really to substitute here..

- The best aproach seems to be this one, but still no results:

(260 + r)² = y² + x²

(150 + r)² = y² + (1000-x)²

y² = (260 + r)² - x²

(150 + r)² = (260 + r)² - x² + (1000-x)²

150² + 300r + r² = 260² + 520r + r² - x² + 1000² - 2000x + x²

Comment: And your efforts have been?

Comment: @FShrike i've been watching this image for an hour, and trying to set up equations and then substitute parts, but so far with no success.. i have tried multiple approaches, also tried to draw it and mathematically calculate the steps accordingly but with no success

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). You're expected to share your work, something that shows that you put some thought and effort on your own to solve the problem before asking for help.

Comment: So welcome. Even if you are sick of them, we want to see your efforts and failed attempts. Failed attempts are fine; they show the answerer how best to help you

Comment: " trying to set up equations and then substitute parts" Which equations did you manage to set up?.  "i have tried multiple approaches" such as ...

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the feedback. I am updating the quesiton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $D=(h,k)$ and $r$ the radius of the circle.

Since the circle pass through $B$ we have $$(500-h)^2+(0-k)^2 = r^2\tag1$$

Since $AD = r+260$ we have $$(h-0)^2+(k-0)^2 = (r+260)^2\tag 2$$

Since $CD = r+150$ we have $$(h-1000)^2+(k-0)^2=(r+150)^2\tag 3$$

The equations $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ are equivalent to

\begin{array}{r}
500^2-2\cdot 500\ h = r^2-h^2-k^2\\
-2\cdot 260\ r-260^2=r^2-h^2-k^2\\
1000^2-2\cdot 1000\ h-2\cdot 150\ r-150^2=r^2-h^2-k^2\\
\end{array}

This means that $$ 500^2-2\cdot 500\ h = -2\cdot 260\ r-260^2=
1000^2-2\cdot 1000\ h-2\cdot 150\ r-150^2$$

This is a system of two linear equations in $h$ and $r$. And I think you should be able to take it from here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. How would this change if also on B there would be a circle and the riclenD would be tangent toball 3 circles?

Comment: Also, on (1) why is it 500-h and not h-500? Thank you

Comment: @sharkyenergy Do you know the equation of a circle?